# php set variable before include and echo it after

Tags: php, oop, class, include, echo

I have an Admin class:

```
<?php
    Class Admin extends Controller{


        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

            function getPage(){
                $num = 5;
                $this->view->load('test');
            }

    }
?>
```

the extended Controller class:

```
<?php

class Controller{

    function __construct() {
        $this->view = new View();
    }

}

?>
```

view class:

```
<?php
Class View{

    function __construct() {

    }

    public function load($file){
        include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/main/views/'.$file.'.php');
    }

}
?>
```

so in the `test.php` file i try to `echo $num;` but i get nothing...

if i try

```
$num = 5;
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/main/views/test.php');
```

**it echos back 5**

whats the problem here?

Comment: when you include the file `test.php` inside the method `load`, `echo $num;` in `test.php` will only print the variable `$num` with scope inside `function load`.

Comment: i see... any work-around on this? i really don't like having includes in every function - thanks

Comment: @fxuser are you using any framework??

Comment: pass the variable in an array like `$data['num'] = 5;$this->view->load('test', $data);`. And in `public function load($file, $data){`, `extract($data);`.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar i don't... i am building a script to sell and using a framework(such as codeigniter) would be overkill i think

Comment: then pass the variable as array as @air4x has specified. That will be a better approach.

Comment: @air4x just checked out Codeigniter way and its exactly that! thats perfect! +9000

Comment: Little advise: You can omit the constructor-Method in The Admin class. This method is automaticaly inherited from Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass associative array  to function `load` as optional parameter and then use `extract` that array to have variables in scope.

```
public function load($file, $data = array()){
    extract($data);

    include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/main/views/'.$file.'.php');
}
```

Or

```
public function load($file, $data = array()){
    foreach ($data as $key => $val)
        ${$key} = $val;

    include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/main/views/'.$file.'.php');
}
```

As my personal experience shows second method is slightly faster.

In function `getPage()` all you need to do is:

```
$this->view->load('test', array('num' => 5));
```

Comment: thats exactly what air4x mentioned on the question comments... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your $num scope is localized to the function getPage and never makes it as a peice of an object. You can modify the function create a function getPage() to return $num and echo it from test.php, or you could rewrite the code as such:

```
<?php
        Class Admin extends Controller{


            function __construct() {
                parent::__construct();
            }

            public $num = 5;

            function getPage(){
                    $this->load->view('test');
                }

        }

    class Controller{

        function __construct() {
            $this->view = new View();
        }

    }

    Class View{

        function __construct() {

        }

        public function load($file){
            echo "I shall skip the file include";
        }

    }

    $test = new Admin();
    echo $test->num;

    ?>
```

You may want to take a look at this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

It'll give you an idea of what visibility options you can implement in the future.